# Can not deduce superclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In the following code, GHC can not find the Functor instance in the definition of `Monoidal` instance.

Why isn't GHC deducing that *given* the `Applicative` constraint is satisfied, then the `Functor` *has* to be somewhere already? (is there a name to this reasoning 'capability' ?)

```
import Prelude hiding (Applicative (..), Monad (..))

class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor f => Monoidal f where
   unit::f ()
   (*) ::f a -> f b -> f (a,b)

instance Applicative f => Monoidal f where
  unit = pure ()
  a * b = undefined
```

I know could of course add an explicit `Functor f` constraint to `Monoidal` to not have the error, but my question is more on why instance resolution works that way

```
import Prelude hiding ((*), Applicative (..), Monad (..))

class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor f => Monoidal f where
   unit::f ()
   (*) ::f a -> f b -> f (a,b)

instance (Applicative f, Functor f) => Monoidal f where
  unit = pure ()
  a * b = (pure (,) <*> a <*> b )

instance (Monoidal f, Functor f) => Applicative f where
  pure x = fmap (\_ -> x) unit
  mu <*> mx = fmap (\(f, x) -> f x) ((mu * mx) :: f (a -> b, a))
```

Comment: I hope it's clear that such an instance doesn't make a lot of sense! – Still, good question, I would also have assumed the compiler to allow this and figure out the superclass.

Comment: The root problem I'm seeing is that you have both "Functor f => Monoidal f" and "Applicative f => Monoidal f".  As I understand it, the compiler needs to see only one possible derivation path for a particular typeclass on a particular type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout because it's an isomorphism back and forth is that what you mean ? that's why I was laying down the iso, to get reminded of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. Here's a minimal file which shows the problem and doesn't rely on any shenanigans with renaming `Prelude` stuff or `undefined`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
class A x
class A x => B x
class A x => C x
instance B x => C x
```

I recommend filing a bug on the GHC bug tracker with this file (or one very like it); the reasoning needed to discover that `B x` implies `A x` should be possible.

Comment: I've reported this as [Trac #14417](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14417)

Comment: And it turned out to be known and officially expected behavior as of 8.0. Weird.

Comment: And [this comment](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11427#comment:4) appears to be the money shot, explaining the problem that is solved by this behavior. It's quite technical, though.

Comment: that was swift.. thank you.  it's somehow for UndecidableSuperclass. (btw UndecidableSuperclass is a thing of beauty)